# How to get HTML code of a .NET control

Tags: c#, .net, html, asp.net-controls

I have a .net panel, and I want to send this panel via outlook to other recipients. For this I think I have to find the html code of this element. How to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the RenderControl method to output the contents to an HtmlTextWriter.

Example, which outputs the content to a StringBuilder.

```
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter(content);
HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sWriter);
pnlMyPanel.RenderControl( htmlWriter );
```

Comment: This is helping me b/c I'm receiving the must be in webform error, if your asp.net control contains any button controls, etc:  http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/122006-1.aspx